# how to send an email automatically when specific criteria in my table are not met

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I just need some guidance, info or links about how I can achieve this.  I am not sure If I can do this from ASP or some kind of stored procedure.  For instance and this is just example, I have 2 fields in my table:
TargetDate
 Status

The expectation is the user has to update  the status field whether it is Complete or Incomplete by the TargetDate that is set in the target date field.  If the target date is passed and the Status field is not updated then I want to send an email to that person.  I just need help on this where to start and what method to use.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what can be done with SQL Server (would not surprise me if it can do it).

Depending on the how much time can lapse from TargetDate before the e-mail gets sent out, you can write up a method in the Global.asax Application_Start method to check on the method and send out e-mails.  This is dependent on how often your application pool is reset and how often someone visits the site.

This does have the advantage of keeping logic in your application as appose to moving business logic to the database (depending on how the program is designed).

Here is an example of what I did in a similar situation:

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var db = new DataContext())
  {

    //Get the last time e-mails where sent out.
    var temp = from s in db.SystemDatas
               select s;


    if (temp.Count() > 0)
    {
      var ts = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Today - temp.First().LastUpdate);

      if ((DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday) && ts.Days > 5)
      {
        //Run President's Report
        Thread PresidentReport = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunPresidentReport));
        PresidentReport.Start();
      }
    }
  }
}

private void RunPresidentReport()
{
  MailMessage oMsg = new MailMessage();
  oMsg.From = new MailAddress("from@at.com");
  oMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@at.com"));
  oMsg.Subject = "Website - President's Report for " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

  var db = new DataContext();
  DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();

  var members = from m in db.Members
                where m.status == 1     //1 = active, 2=inactive
                orderby m.lastName, m.firstName
                select m;

  var sb = new StringBuilder();

  /** Code to generate body cut for simplicity **/

  if (sb.Length > 0)
  {
    oMsg.Body = sb.ToString();

    var emailClient = new SmtpClient();
    emailClient.Send(oMsg);

    var Data = from s in db.SystemDatas
               select s;

    if (Data.Count() > 0)
    {
      Data.First().LastUpdate = DateTime.Today;
      db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
    }
  }
}
```

Then put the SMTP settings into the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="NO_REPLY@at.com">
        <network host="localhost"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, i only need to check and send the email once every day and it could be anytime.  Can you guide me some more info about the Global.asax and how this is done?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using SQL Server:

**Step 1**: [Configure component 'Database Mail XPs'](http://microsoft.productiveedge.com/sending-email-from-sql-server/)

**Step 2**: Create a storedprocedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP
AS

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = someValue)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @Result INT
        EXEC 
        @Result =  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @RECIPIENTS     = 'EMAILADDRESS1,EMAILADDRESS2,EMAILADDRESSN',
        @SUBJECT        = 'Subject',
        @BODY           = 'Body',
        @BODY_FORMAT    = 'HTML'

        SELECT Result = @Result 
   END
```

**You need to modify this procedure accordingly**.